# windows batch file script to pick random files from a folder and move them to another folder

Tags: random, file, batch-file

I need a batch script to randomly select X number of files in a folder and move them to another folder. How do I write a windows batch script that can do this?

Comment: Does this have to be in Batch? It would be much simpler to implement in PowerShell.

Comment: I don't know how to use Powershell. But i can try it. Please help me.

Answer (score 17):

(I'm assuming that your *X* is known beforehand – represented by the variable `$x` in the following code).

Since you weren't adverse to a PowerShell solution:

```
Get-ChildItem SomeFolder | Get-Random -Count $x | Move-Item -Destination SomeOtherFolder
```

or shorter:

```
gci somefolder | random -c $x | mi -dest someotherfolder
```

Comment: i entered `Get-ChildItem C:\temp\source | Get-Random -Count 100 | Move-Item -Destination C:\temp\output` into powershell console but nothing happened

Comment: @Joey, I tried this in PowerShell because I'm trying to get a script to randomly change my Log-on screen. My source directory was several folders deep in my user directory, and for some reason the Move-Item command threw an error when I tried to execute. It said `Cannot find path 'C:\Users\<username>\<random desktop.png>' because it does not exist.` Basically it found a random file in my source directory, but then it screwed up the path, pointing to a nonexistent file in the top level of my user directory. Any idea why?

Comment: @rironin, I edited Joey's original script to fix the error. When getting the items from the folder, we need to get the FullName of the file, before passing it to Get-Random

Answer (score 3):

The following Batch code will do it. Note that you will need to launch cmd using the following command line:

```
cmd /v:on
```

to enable delayed environment variable expansion. Note also that it will pick a random number of files from 0 to 32767 - you will probably want to modify this part to fit your requirements!

```
@ECHO OFF
SET SrcCount=0
SET SrcMax=%RANDOM%
FOR %F IN (C:\temp\source\*.*) DO IF !SrcCount! LSS %SrcMax% (
      SET /A SrcCount += 1
      ECHO !SrcCount! COPY %F C:\temp\output
      COPY %F C:\temp\output
      )
```

Comment: what i did was copy the code to the powershell console. i'm afraid it didn't work. it gave me errors that are in red text.

Comment: Hi techdaemon - The code I posted was Batch, which is a completely different language from PowerShell. I've updated the Batch code and it should work now, as long as you use "/v:on" as I state.

Comment: It's a batch file. why did you copy it to powershell console and expect it to work?

Comment: the "SrcCount" is where i specify the number of files to pick, isn't it?

Comment: No - that's a counter so it knows how many files it has copied. SrcMax is the number of files to copy. I've set it be a random number as that's what the question asked for.

Comment: @RB I need something where I can specify the number of random files that will be selected. I'm sorry if you misunderstood the question. @kurumi Pardon me for my naivete.

Comment: @techdaemon Do you want to be able to specify the number of files, or specify the range of a random number of files?

Comment: @RB I want to be able to specify the number of files please.

Comment: In that case, simply set SrcMax to be the value you want. E.g. `SET SrcMax=25` to copy 25 files.

Comment: Thanks, but still it does not work. i saved the code to something.bat and double clicked it but no files appeared in C:\temp\output. I made sure I copied my source files to C:\temp\source\. And about `cmd \v:on` i don't understand how it works with the rest of the code you wrote. Again, sorry for my naivete.

Comment: Click "Start" -> "Run" and type in `cmd \v:on`. This will launch a command prompt. Now run your batch file **inside** that command prompt. It should work ok. Obviously, you will need to set the source and output folders to something on your machine, and make sure you've updated `SrcMax`.

Comment: Still doesn't work. It gives me many "The system cannot find the file specified" error. But the filenames are being shown. I'm not sure if the reason is the spaces and special characters in the filenames.

Comment: (a) It should be `cmd /v:on` (a backslash is not a slash). (b) what you're written there will *only* work in the interactive shell, not in a batch file. (c) You probably want a few quotes to properly handle file names with spaces.

Answer (score 2):

## here is a CMD code, which outputs the random file name (customize it to your needs):

```
@echo off & setlocal
set "workDir=C:\source\folder"
::Read the %random%, two times is'nt a mistake! Why? Ask Bill.
::In fact at the first time %random% is nearly the same.
@set /a "rdm=%random%"
set /a "rdm=%random%"
::Push to your path.
pushd "%workDir%"
::Count all files in your path. (dir with /b shows only the filenames)
set /a "counter=0"
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b ^|find "."') do call :sub1
::This function gives a value from 1 to upper bound of files
set /a "rdNum=(%rdm%*%counter%/32767)+1"
::Start a random file
set /a "counter=0"
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b ^|find "."') do set "fileName=%%i" &call :sub2
::Pop back from your path.
popd "%workDir%"
goto :eof
:: end of main
:: start of sub1
:sub1
::For each found file set counter + 1.
set /a "counter+=1"
goto :eof
:: end of sub1
:: start of sub2
:sub2
::1st: count again,
::2nd: if counted number equals random number then start the file.
set /a "counter+=1"
if %counter%==%rdNum% (
:: OUTPUT ALERT BOX with FILENAME
MSG * "%fileName%"
)
goto :eof
:: end of sub2
```

Comment: LOL Ask Bill :D

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd \particular\folder
set n=0
for %%f in (*.*) do (
   set /A n+=1
   set "file[!n!]=%%f"
)
set /A "rand=(n*%random%)/32768+1"
copy "!file[%rand%]!" \different\folder
```

from [Need to create a batch file to select one random file from a folder and copy to another folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18945521/need-to-create-a-batch-file-to-select-one-random-file-from-a-folder-and-copy-to)

Comment: [Check this](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-random.html) for explanation on `%random%`

Answer (score 0):

A sample **Powershell code** that Moves ***1000*** *Random* files From **C:\Test\A**  To  **C:\Test\B**

```
$d = gci "C:\Test\A" | resolve-path  |  get-random -count 1000
```

Press *Enter* key and then execute below code

```
Move-Item $d  -destination "C:\Test\B"
```

Don't forget to add ***"*** mark *before* and *after* the path of the folders