# Batch command that checks folders, outputs file count, and acts through if statements based on file count

Tags: file, batch-file, directory, batch-processing

To start...I'm entirely self taught...most of which I gleaned from this forum by cannibalizing and appropriating code (and I just made an account to ask this question...so if I screwed something up please tell me)...regardless a specific set of commands are giving me some issues

I was trying to use [batch file - counting number of files in folder and storing in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004045/batch-file-counting-number-of-files-in-folder-and-storing-in-a-variable?newreg=1528048d8ee74f4e93f19760582761b0) and [Windows Batch file to move X number of files from folder to folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123875/windows-batch-file-to-move-x-number-of-files-from-folder-to-folder) and I've hit a roadblock.

I suppose I don't quite grasp the syntax but here's a sample test/proof of concept test code...

```
@echo
set Zan=0
set In=0
set Out=0
set Limit=5
timeout 5
for %%A in (C:\zan1011out\*.*) do set /a Zan+=1
for %%B in (C:\messagesin\*.*) do set /a In+=1
for %%C in (C:\messagesout\*.*) do set /a Out+=1
cd "C:\"
echo %Zan% in Zan1011out, %In% in MessagesIn, and %Out% in MessagesOut
timeout 5
if %In% gtr %Limit% goto :In_Shuffle
if %Out% gtr %Limit% goto :Out_Shuffle
echo failed
timeout 5
exit
:In_Shuffle
echo MessagesIn needs to be shuffled. Please Wait
timeout 5
exit
:Out_Shuffle
echo MessagesOut needs to be shuffled. Please Wait
timeout 5
exit
```

Files are in these folders: "C:\zan1011out\", "C:\messagesin\", and "C:\messagesout\". The program would need to set a variable for each folder and increment the variable based on file count in each folder. After the batch would have the variable called again later for an if statement. It's not a part yet but my intent would be to expand it out into forcing a file move from those source folders to a temp folder, then having the batch re-inject them in smaller groups (ala "spoon-feeding" a different program with files that can and often jam it).

Edit: Changed sleep to timeout, command now runs, after some testing now seems to work...now time to add in the rest...

Comment: You are aware that Windows doesn't have a default `sleep` command, so that would have to have been added. _You can use the built-in `timeout` command though, enter **`timeout /?`** at the prompt for more info_.

Comment: I didn't know, and this batch would only be operated between XP and 10, but all the same I appreciate it

And I tested with your suggestion and that seemed to make most of the difference as it runs now...just need to work on the if statements now...