# Need to create a batch file to select one random file from a folder and copy to another folder

Tags: file, batch-file, copy

I need to create a batch file for Windows OS that will select a random file from a particular folder, then copy that file to a different folder.  I still need a copy of that file to remain in the original location.

FYI, it needs to be a batch file.

Thanks in advance for your help...

Comment: Batch file for what kind of operating system? Windows, linuxes (+unix) and OS X have different languages to implements such functionality.

Comment: Windows... sorry that I didn't specify this from the beginning.  I will edit the question to reflect the operating system.

Comment: @Cheri: That is not necessary; the `batch-file` tag clearly indicate: "Script files containing a series of commands that are executed by the Windows command-line interpreter".

Comment: Okay, I will accept it... just testing it out first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd \particular\folder
set n=0
for %%f in (*.*) do (
   set /A n+=1
   set "file[!n!]=%%f"
)
set /A "rand=(n*%random%)/32768+1"
copy "!file[%rand%]!" \different\folder
```

Comment: Just to be clear, I just copy this entire code and replace the file paths, correct?

Comment: "access is denied" :(

Comment: Xcopy worked where copy didn't.  I just had to add the /Y /I switches

Comment: I would need some information: how do I make sure the batch keep generating random numbers?

Comment: The code above was giving me the same random number on each run. 
(Windows 11)

I changed the following line which fixed the problem, from:
`set /A "rand=(n*%random%)/32768+1"`
to
`set /A "rand=%random% %% n + 1"`

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
set/a %%/folder
/a copy <folder2>
```