# Is there a way to create a .bat who copy a random file from a directory to another writing the file name in a txt too?

Tags: batch-file

I created the following .bat in order to copy a random .mp4 file from a directory A into a directory B (with a fixed file name `video.mp4`). So, in the directory A there is a pool of .mp4 file, and in the directory B there is the the file video.mp4 (same name, but different video every time I execute my `batch-file`).

That's a code who do this. It perfectly works.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd C:\Users\aless\Desktop\....DIRECTORY A
set n=0
for %%f in (*.*) do (
   set /A n+=1
   set "file[!n!]=%%f"
)
for /L %%i in (1,1,%time:~-1%) do set "dummy=!random!"
set /A "rand=(n*%random%)/32768+1"
copy "!file[%rand%]!" C:\Users\aless\Desktop\....DIRECTORY B\video.mp4
```

That's the question:

I want to add a file named "title.txt" (fixed name) in the directory B and I want that the original name of the .mp4 file chosen randomly will be written (before the copy action) into the content of the title.txt (without `.mp4` extension).

So, at the end... every time I execute the .bat file, a random file have to be copied from directory A to directory B with a fixed file name (video.mp4) and the title.txt content have to be updated and substituted at the same time with the original file name without extensions.

How can I can add this operation in my code?

Thanks a lot

How can I do to add this feature to my code?

Comment: I bet you got that code from the answer by Aacini in [`this question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18945521/need-to-create-a-batch-file-to-select-one-random-file-from-a-folder-and-copy-to#18946519). `:)` Though I understand why you are using a text file, you do not need to use a file, you already have the content of the directory, just use it, like that answer also demonstrated.

Comment: `FOR %%G IN ("!file[%rand%]!") DO >"C:\Users\aless\Desktop\DIRECTORY B\title.txt" ECHO %%~nG`

Comment: Yes you won the bet Gerhard :) anyway i need to write the .mp4 file name (without extension) in the content of txt file (not in the txt file name) because i will run an external software who read that content of title.txt. I m not so expert in coding but I will try to add the squashman  line soon. Where have I to place it exactly?

Comment: It perfectly works!!! Thank you to you all